# Find range of values of $a,b,c$ such that $ax^2+bx+c$ satisfies given conditions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, quadratics

Let $y = f(x) = ax^2+bx+c$ where $a\neq0$. Find the range of values $a,b$ and $c$ such that it satisfies the following:

- $0 \le f(x) \le 1 \quad \forall \space x \in [0,1]$

---

What I have found so far?

1. For $x=0$, we get $0 \le c \le 1$
2. For $x=1$, we get $0 \le a+b+c \le 1$
3. If roots exist, then they should lie outside the interval $[0,1]$.

   Therefore, ${{-b - \sqrt{D}}\over{2a}} < 0$ and ${{-b + \sqrt{D}}\over{2a}} >1$. I tried to solve these but didn't get any fruitful results.

   EDIT 1: As explained in comments by @insipidintegrator, this is only for **distinct** roots.
4. Vertex of quadratic $f(x)$ is $\big( \frac{-b}{2a}, -\frac{D}{4a}\big)$. If the x-coordinate of the vertex lies between 0 and 1, then y-coordinate should also be between 0 and 1. But I have no idea how to proceed from here.

I want to find some lower/upper limits for $a,b,c$ or any kind of relation between them.  Any solution or hints for solving this problem is greatly appreciated.

Comment: “_If roots exist, they should lie outside the interval [0,1]_” should be refined to “_If_ ___distinct___ _roots exist, they should lie outside the interval [0,1]_” I think I understand your thought process behind this: If root exists, then parabola must go into the fourth quadrant. However, it is very much possible to be tangent to X axis at a point in [0,1] without violating any conditions.

Comment: @insipidintegrator The roots can be $x=0,1$, take $-4\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2}+1$

Comment: Ah, so I think I’ll put an edit: the corrected line should have (0,1) instead of [0,1]. (Can’t edit comment now so putting it here)

Comment: Got [this from WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=0%3C%3Dax%5E2%2Bbx%2Bc%3C%3D1).

Comment: @InanimateBeing thanks, that's awesome. I found this as well [solve ax^2+bx+c in wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+0%3C%3Dax%5E2%2Bbx%2Bc%3C%3D1)

Comment: @impopularGuy glad it was helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may obtain the necessary and sufficient conditions for
$$a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}, ~ 0 \le ax^2 + bx + c \le 1, \forall x \in [0, 1].$$

**Fact 1**: Let $A, B, C \in \mathbb{R}$. Then
$$Ax^2 + Bx + C \ge 0, ~ x \ge 0
\iff A \ge 0, ~ C \ge 0, ~ B \ge -\sqrt{4AC}.$$
(The proof is given at the end.)

**Fact 2**: Let $A, B, C \in \mathbb{R}$. Then
$$Ax^2 + Bx + C \ge 0, ~ x\in [0, 1] \iff 
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
 A + B + C \ge 0\\[5pt]
 C \ge 0\\[5pt]
 B + 2C \ge - \sqrt{4(A + B + C)C}.
\end{array}
\right.
$$
(The proof is given at the end.)

Now, using Fact 2, we have
$$ax^2 + bx + c \ge 0, ~ x \in [0, 1]
\iff 
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
 a + b + c \ge 0\\[5pt]
 c \ge 0\\[5pt]
 b + 2c \ge - \sqrt{4(a + b + c)c}
\end{array}
\right.$$
and
$$ - ax^2 - bx - c + 1 \ge 0,~ x \in [0, 1]$$
$$\iff 
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
 -a - b - c + 1 \ge 0\\[5pt]
 - c + 1 \ge 0\\[5pt]
 - b + 2(-c + 1) \ge - \sqrt{4(-a - b - c + 1)(-c + 1)}.
\end{array}
\right.$$

Thus, we have
$$0 \le ax^2 + bx + c \le 1, ~ x\in [0, 1]$$
$$\iff \left\{\begin{array}{l}
 0 \le a + b + c \le 1\\[5pt]
 0 \le c \le 1\\[5pt]
 b + 2c \ge - \sqrt{4(a + b + c)c}\\[5pt]
 b + 2c \le 2 + \sqrt{4(-a - b - c + 1)(-c + 1)}.
\end{array}
\right.$$

$\phantom{2}$

---

*Proof of Fact 1*:

“$\Longleftarrow$”: $\quad$ For $x\ge 0$, we have $Ax^2+Bx+C\ge Ax^2 - \sqrt{4AC}\ x + C = (x\sqrt{A} - \sqrt{C})^2\ge 0$.

“$\Longrightarrow$”: $\quad$ Clearly, $A \ge 0$ and $C \ge 0$.

If $B < - \sqrt{4AC}$ and $AC > 0$,
then $Ax_0^2 + Bx_0 + C < 0$ where $x_0 = \sqrt{\frac{C}{A}} > 0$. Contradiction.

If $B < - \sqrt{4AC}$ and $AC = 0$,
there exists $x_1 > 0$ such that $Ax_1^2 + Bx_1 + C < 0$ (easy). Contradiction.

We are done.

$\phantom{2}$

*Proof of Fact 2*:

By Fact 1, it suffices to prove that
$$Ax^2 + Bx + C \ge 0, ~ x\in [0, 1]
\iff (A + B + C)s^2 + (B + 2C)s + C \ge 0, ~ s \ge 0.$$

“$\Longleftarrow$”: $\quad$ Clearly, $A+B+C \ge 0$.

If $x = 1$, then $Ax^2 + Bx + C = A + B + C \ge 0$.

If $x\in [0, 1)$, letting $s = \frac{x}{1 - x} \ge 0$, we have
$x = \frac{s}{1+s}$ and
$$Ax^2 + Bx + C = \frac{1}{(1+s)^2}[(A+B+C)s^2+(B+2C)s+C] \ge 0.$$

“$\Longrightarrow$”: $\quad$ For $s\ge 0$, letting $x = \frac{s}{1+s}\in [0,1]$, we have
$$Ax^2+Bx+C = \frac{1}{(1+s)^2}[(A+B+C)s^2+(B+2C)s+C] \ge 0$$
which results in
$(A+B+C)s^2+(B+2C)s+C\ge 0$.

We are done.

Comment: This is awesome and better that what i have achieved, but there seems to be a problem. If we create limits for all three variables, first we have  $0\leq c\leq 1$. Second $-\sqrt{4kc}-2c\leq b\leq 2-\sqrt{4(1-k)(1-c)}-2c$ where $k=a+b+c$ and $0\leq k\leq 1$. Finally $-b-c\leq a\leq 1-b-c$. I used these limits and [plotted in desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/pmdhdganew). Try playing with the sliders for a,b and c. It seems like for some values $f(x)<0$ where $0<x<1$

Comment: My bad.  limits for $b$ is $-\sqrt{4kc}-2c\leq b\leq 2+\sqrt{4(1-k)(1-c)}-2c$. But still results are same. Some values of a,b,c in these limits doesn't satisfy original condition. My observation is that this happens when $f(x)$ is not monotonous in $x \in [0,1]$.

Comment: @impopularGuy Can you give some example of $a, b, c$?

Comment: @impopularGuy Also, did you notice $k = a + b + c$ which contains $b$?

Comment: You are right. My bad again. Final limits will be  $0\leq c\leq 1$, $0\leq k\leq 1$, $-\sqrt{4kc}-2c\leq b\leq 2+\sqrt{4(1-k)(1-c)}-2c$ and $a = k-b-c$. Thanks, this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: @impopularGuy Glad it was helpful.

Comment: @impopularGuy Honestly, my reasoning is complicated. As Erik pointed out, since $f$ is quadratic, its shape is simple, and the conditions are easy to obtain (you were already quite closed). The other two answers are both correct and simpler. You may unaccept my answer and accept the other answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since $f$ is of degree 2, its shape it quite simple. Depending on how you want to write your ranges in your answer, I think you were already quite close.

If $f$ is an increasing function on the domain $[0,1]$, then we only have to check your conditions 1 and 2 (try to visualize this).
The same is true if $f$ is an decreasing function on the domain $[0,1]$.

The only exception is when $f$ changes from increasing to decreasing (or vice versa) in the interval $[0,1]$. This happens if $0 \leq \dfrac{-b}{2a} \leq 1$, this is the vertex you mention.
In this case we also need that $0 \leq -\dfrac{b^2-4ac}{2a} \leq 1$.

Comment: I have been visualizing all this using desmos.com. What I am looking for is some concrete limits or stronger relations between the a,b, and c for all scenarios.

Comment: I don't think you can write the relations of one of the scenarios in the form $a_1 \leq a \leq a_2$, $b_1 \leq b \leq b_2$ and $c_1 \leq c \leq c_2$ for *constants* $a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2,c_1,c_2$. So, I'm not sure what you mean with concrete and stronger relations.

Comment: For example, $0\leq c \leq 1$ is a good constraint, but since a and b can be -ve, many values that satisfy $0 \leq a+b+c \leq 1$ fail to satisfy the actual condition. Hence more constraints are required.

Comment: As an example, if we look at the scenario where $f$ is increasing on the interval $[0,1]$ and $a > 0$, then we can write your condition as the following 4 constraints: $0 \leq c \leq 1$, $0 \leq a+b+c \leq 1$, $a>0$ and $0 > \frac{-b}{2a}$. Any $a,b,c$ satisfying all these 4 equations simultaneously will satisfy your condition.

Answer (score 1):

You have $0\le f(x) \le 1$ on $[0,1]$ if and only if $f(0)$, $f(1) \in [0,1]$ and $(\ -\frac{b}{2a} \in [0,1] \implies -\frac{\Delta}{4 a} \in [0, 1]\ )$, that is all of the conditions below are satisfied

1. $ c\in [0,1]$
2. $a + b + c \in [0,1]$
3. $ - \frac{b}{2 a } \not \in [0,1]$ or $-\frac{\Delta}{4 a} \in [0,1]$